# Why does an array reverse itself outside of a useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

There is an array called `recent` that contains the values of an input when a form is submitted. Let's say the array contains the values 'London' and 'Paris'. Inside the `useEffect`, the array would return `[London, Paris]` as it should. However, outside the `useEffect`, the array would return the values `[Paris, London]` - the reverse.

At first, I thought that it was due to a second array `list` that was assigned the reverse of the `recent` array inside the `useEffect`, but this is not the case as the `recent` array still returns the values correct order after the reverse is assigned to `list`. The `recent` array is reassigned to `list` every time a new value is added to `recent` so that `list` is always the reverse of `recent`.

How do I fix this?

```
const [recent, setRecent] = useState([]);
const [reverse, setReverse] = useState(true); // says whether to reverse list or not
const [list, setList] = useState();

const RecentSearches = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (reverse) {
      console.log(recent, "before reverse"); // returns ['London', 'Paris']
      setList(() => recent.reverse()); // reverses recent
      setReverse(false); // does not reverse list every time the function runs - only reverses it once
      console.log(recent, "after reverse"); // returns ['London', 'Paris']
      console.log(recent[0], "first item"); // returns 'London'
    }
  }, []);

  let searches;
  console.log("============");
  console.log(recent); // returns ['Paris', 'London']
  console.log(recent[0], "first item"); // returns 'Paris' 
  console.log("---------");
  console.log(list); // returns ['Paris', 'London']
  console.log("============");

  if (list) {
    searches = list.map((value, index) => ( <
      button type = "submit"
      form = "form"
      key = {
        index
      }
      onClick = {
        () => setSearch(value)
      }
      onMouseEnter = {
        () => setSearch(value)
      }
      onMouseLeave = {
        () => setSearch("")
      } > {
        value
      } <
      i className = "fa-solid fa-chevron-right" > < /i> < /
      button >
    ));
  } else {
    searches = "";
  }
  return searches;
};

const [search, setSearch] = useState(""); // value in the input

const handleSubmit = async event => {
  console.log("form submitted");
  event.preventDefault();
  setRecent([...recent, search]); // adds search value to end of recent array
  setReverse(true); // means that list will be set to reverse of recent with the new value
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.reverse` is **destructive** which means that by doing `recent.reverse()` you're actually reversing `recent`. You should do instead

```
setList([...recent].reverse())
```

So you're not changing directly `recent`